# what's wrong with the R.id in my program?

Tags: android

the mainactivity.java

```
package sxhay.android.HelloAndroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button mButton1 = (Button) findViewbyid(R.id.buttona);
        Button mButton2 = (Button) findViewbyid(R.id.buttonb);
    }
}
```

the main.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/hi"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"/>
    
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/buttona"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Activity A"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/buttonb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Activity B"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

it say i need to import android.R, but when i was imported, 'buttonb(and a)' was wrong and just get me a red sign.
how can i solve this program?

Comment: can you post your logcat ...

Comment: If we don't know the error/exception we would just be guessing.

Comment: Please add a question. Also add what have you tried so far along with error message or stack-trace whichever is applicable. Also indent your code by four spaces so it is recognized properly by Stackoverflow. This will help fellow Stackoverflow users understand your problem and solve it quickly.
Go through [this](Please add a question. Also add what have you tried so far along with error message or stack-trace whichever is applicable. Also indent your code by four spaces so it is recognized properly by Stackoverflow. This will help others understand your problem and solve it quickly.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might guide you formulating a better question.

Comment: Try to clean the project.

Answer (score 0):

As max59 suggested try to clean the project and restart eclipse will help.